# Laravel 4.2 Sync multidimensional array in pivot table

Tags: laravel-4, pivot-table

These are my tables with relation ship functions.

issues table

```
id
issueName
```

Every Issue has multiple question

In Issue.php model

```
public function questions() {
        return $this->hasMany('Question','issueID','id');
    }
```

questions table

```
id
issueID
questionText
questionScore
```

every question belong to an Issue, it has its corresponding score

In Question.php model

```
public function issues() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Issue');
    }
```

Using radio input I am selecting a question for each Issue, and geting an array of questionID, score which is intended to save in the pivot table.

assessments table

```
id
totalScore
```

in Assessment.php model

```
public function scores() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Question','assessments_question_score','assessmentsID','id');
        }
```

in Question.php model

```
public function assessments() {
            return $this->belongsToMany('Assessment');
        }
```

assessments_question_score table

```
id
assessmentsID
questionID
score
```

when I am trying to sync questionID, score to assessments_question_score table using

```
$assessments = New Assessment;
...
...
$assessments->save();
$assessments->scores()->sync($questionIDscore);
```

but it is not working, Is it wrong to sync multi dimentional array in sync or something else I am missing? How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Why do you have ´table´ in the association-functions? return $this->belongsToMany('Question','assessments_question_score table','assessmentsID','id'); Should be: return $this->belongsToMany('Question','assessments_question_score','assessmentsID','id');

Comment: Do you use this as questionIDscore? array(1 => array('score' => 10))

Comment: Also you dont specify a pivot in the belongsToMany statements. return $this->belongsToMany('Question','assessments_question_score','assessmentsID','id')->withPivot('score');

Comment: I think that a typo, but not in my source

Comment: $questionIDscore is an array of questionID and score, so if I add
withPivot('questionID', 'score'); will it work for 
$assessments->scores()->sync($questionIDscore);

Comment: No, This doesn't work just passing the array for withPivot way.

Comment: In the withpivot, you should only pass the fields that are in the pivot table. Then in the sync function you can pass the data. QuestionID isn't needed in the pivot data. It's already used for the many-to-many relation.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand.
fields within the withPivot method are in the pivot table? what should i pass to sync? the input array $questionScore?? it doesnt work, error integrity constraint violation happens.

Comment: you mentioned array(1 => array('score' => 10)) earlier
i think to pass in sync method
but if you can explain this it will be helpful, what is 1 used for or in mycase how should i write it?

Comment: This is in the documentation: $user->roles()->sync(array(1 => array('expires' => true)));

Comment: So you should pass an array with the ids as key and as value an array with the pivot data. So in your case the 'score' value.

Comment: Does a question have a fixed score? Or does it have a score for each assessment?

Comment: each question has its fixed score

Comment: Then you don't have to put in a score in the pivot. You just have to connect the questions to the assessment. Then just pass an array of question ids to the sync function.

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY' (SQL: insert into `assessments_question_score` (`assessmentsID`, `id`) values (5, 1)) is happening? did I defined the relationships wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assessment.php

```
public function questions() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('Question','assessments_question_score','assessmentsID','questionID');
}
```

Question.php

```
public function assessments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Assessment','assessments_question_score','questionID','assessmentsID'););
}
```

Then you can connect questions to an assessment like this:

```
$questionIds = array(2,5,6);

$assessment = new Assessment;
$assessment->save();
$assessment->questions()->sync($questionIds);
```

Questions with id 2, 5 and 6 are then connected to the assessment.

To get the score of the first question:

```
$questionScore = $assessment->questions()->first->questionScore;
```

To get the totalscore of all questions:

```
$totalScore = $assessment->questions()->sum('questionScore');
```

To get the average score of all questions:

```
$averageScore = $assessment->questions()->avg('questionScore');
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many
Also search for 'sync'.

Comment: Its working good without errors like earlier, but the array I am syncing works fine when i write
$assessment->questions()->sync(array_key($questionIds));
but the score field remains empty
can I pass array_values($questonIds) for score field along with keys which are basically ids from question table.

Comment: Don't you have a duplicate field there? Because you have a score field on the question table and on the pivot table (assessments_question_score). You said all questions have a fixed score, so you only need the score field to be on the questions table. Do you want to edit the questionScore on syncing? That's not possible (as far as I know)